# merge two plot to one graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataframe

I have two dataframe, and I plot both of them.
one is for female and the other for male.

[image]

I want merge them in one graph with different color
(since they have same feature)

here are codes

```
female[feature].plot(kind='bar')
male[feature].plot(kind = "bar")
```

feature is the column name of data frame.
the date frame is look likes

```
          X1  X2  X3 ..... X46
male     100  65  75 ..... 150
female   500  75  30 ..... 350
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) with transposing `DataFrame` by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
'X2': {'female': 75, 'male': 65}, 
'X46': {'female': 350, 'male': 150}, 
'X1': {'female': 500, 'male': 100}, 
'X3': {'female': 30, 'male': 75}})
print (df)
         X1  X2  X3  X46
female  500  75  30  350
male    100  65  75  150

df.T.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: thank you very much! one more question, can I change the color by gender??

Comment: I got it! using color = ["r","b"]